# Python Regular Expression Matching Many Times

Tags: python, regex

I would like to as a basic Python regular expression problem.
I have a dataset

```
line = "(1,2) (2,3)"
```

That can repeat many times so line can also be

```
line = "(1,2) (3,4) (6,5)"
```

I have a regular expression

```
rx = "(\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)\s*){2,}$"
```

I want

```
a = re.match(rx,line).groups();
```

to match

```
('(1,2)','(3,4)'...)
```

But I can only match the last (6,5). I need the last $ because I don't know how many bracketed inputs I can have, otherwise an incorrect input such as

```
(1,2),(3,4),(5,6
```

will pass the regexp.

any tips?

Edit:
Added the fact that the data was not exactly formatted as detailed. Instead

```
line= 'blah(1,2) (2,3)blah'
```

So indeed regular expressions are needed

Thanks

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use regular expressions (I'm not a regex specialist, but it worked with the given data):

```
r = "[\(\d+,\d+\)]{1,}"
c = re.findall(r,line)
```

or else follow nightcracker's excellent suggestion. Most often the simplest answer is the better answer.

**EDIT**: Thanks to Joran Beasley for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Behold, the magic of **no** regular expressions:

```
>>> "(1,2) (3,4) (6,5)".split()
['(1,2)', '(3,4)', '(6,5)']
```

Comment: Perhaps this would work in normal cases but I omitted the fact that I have garbage before and garbage after the input: so line = (blah(1,2) (2,3) blah)

Comment: i suspect its not actually garbage and it would be better to trim out the "garbage" then use a simple split ... at least thats my guess

Answer (score 1):

try using `re.findall(rx, line)`

Comment: `xx=re.findall("(\([^)]*\))","(1,2) (2,3)" )` should work ... but see nightcrackers answer ...

Comment: agreed, nightcracker's answer is more "pythonic" -- it's easier to read and modify. only use REs if your text parsing is very complicated, or if you're doing so much of it that speed is an issue

Answer (score 0):

Note that Borgleader's answer leads to:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[\(\d+,\d+\)]{1,}', '(1, 2),(2,3)')
['(1,', '2),(2,3)']
```

Joran Beasley's answer for the above case gives:

```
re.findall(r"(\([^)]*\))", '(1, 2),(2,3)')
['(1, 2)', '(2,3)']
```

But is too inclusive:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\([^)]*\))", '(1, blah2),(2,3)')
['(1, blah2)', '(2,3)']
```

If you wish to include only numbers, then:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)', '(1, 2),(2,3)')
['(1, 2)', '(2,3)']
>>> re.findall(r'\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)', '(1, blah2),(2,3)')
['(2,3)']
>>> re.findall(r'\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)', '(1, 2),(2,3) (6, 5')
['(1, 2)', '(2,3)']
```

If you want to remove any spaces in the final result:

```
>>> [x.replace(' ', '') for x in re.findall(r'\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)', '(1, 2),(2,3) (6, 5')]
['(1,2)', '(2,3)']
```

Or if there are tabs and such:

```
>>> sp = re.compile('\s')
>>> [sp.sub('', x) for x in re.findall(r'\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)', '(1, 2),( 2, 3 ) (6, 5')]
['(1,2)', '(2,3)']
```

Of course, the simplest for your data set the better.